# XMPP can login on iOS simulator but can't login on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp

this is my code , about xmpp login

```
- (void)connect{
    if (self.xmppStream == nil) {
        self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
        [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    }

    if (![self.xmppStream isConnected]) {
        XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithUser:_userName.text domain:@"kwjdemacbook-pro.local" resource:nil];
        [self.xmppStream setMyJID:jid];
        [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"192.168.16.74"];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:20.0 error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"connect Error:%@",[[error userInfo] description]);
        }
    }
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"123456" error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Authenticate Error:%@",[[error userInfo] description]);
    }
}
```

XMPP can login on iOS simulator and send mesage but can't login on iphone.

Comment: my computer ip : 192.168.16.74  mask:255.255.255.0   my iphone connect my computer wifi  and my iphone ip:192.168.2.4

Comment: i change [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"192.168.2.1"];   Results the same

Comment: Are you sure your iPhone is on the same network that your local Mac server ? Are you sure the port for your Mac are not blocked by firewall ? This looks like a network configuration issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to set port number for XMPPStream,

Try this,

```
- (void)connect{
    if (self.xmppStream == nil) {
        self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
        [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    }

    if (![self.xmppStream isConnected]) {
        XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithUser:_userName.text domain:@"kwjdemacbook-pro.local" resource:nil];
        [self.xmppStream setMyJID:jid];
        [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"192.168.16.74"];

  // setPort number of your openfire server
[self.xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:20.0 error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"connect Error:%@",[[error userInfo] description]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had try it ,but can't connect on iphone